# MS SQL Server - Select group of max n results of multiple columns in join query result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table 1**

---

```
| Customer_ID | Template_ID  
---------------------
| C1   |  T1   |    
| C1   |  T2   |    

| C2   |  T100   |    
| C2   |  T5   |    
---------------------
```

**Table 2**

```
---------------------
| Template_ID | Product_ID  
---------------------
| T1   |  P1   |    
| T1   |  P2   |    
| T1   |  P5   |    

| T2    |  P10   |    
| T2    |  P45   |    

| T100   |  P98   |    
| T100   |  P78   |    

| T5   |  P7777   |    
| T5   |  P9   |    
| T5   |  P10   |    
| T5   |  P1   |
```

**Join query result:**

```
------------------------------------------
| Customer_ID | Template_ID  | Product_ID  
------------------------------------------
| C1          |  T1          |  P1
| C1          |  T1          |  P2
| C1          |  T1          |  P5

| C1          |  T2          |  P10
| C1          |  T2          |  P45

| C2          |  T100          |  P98
| C2          |  T100          |  P78

| C2          |  T5          |  P7777
.
.
```

I have an existing join query which returns all the matches for Customer_ID & Template_ID, I want to restrict to get only the latest  'Templates for customers - Customer_ID & Template_ID '.

Expected output:

Customer_ID         Template_ID         Product ID

C1                  T1                  P1

C1                  T1                  P2

C1                  T1                  P5

C2                  T100                  P98

C2                  T100                  P78

PS: Actually I want the latest 10, for easier understanding I mention as only the recent Customer_ID & Template_ID  combination . I have a date column in Table1 , and I got 'order by SAVED_DATE DESC' , so in the result set I want to get the first one. I have other tables as part of join, which I haven't provided to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make `count` window function by `Customer_ID` and `Template_ID` columns in t CTE result.

then use a correlated subquery `exists` to get the `max` count from etc.

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT t1.Template_ID,
           t1.Customer_ID,
           t2.Product_ID,
           COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer_ID,t2.Template_ID) cnt
    FROM t1 
    join t2 on t1.Template_ID = t2.Template_ID
)
select Template_ID,
        Customer_ID,
    Product_ID
from cte c1
where exists (
    select 1 
    from cte cc
    where c1.Customer_ID = cc.Customer_ID
    having max(cc.cnt) = c1.cnt 
)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e244556492b4529ba9a3888b0aa4b7d0)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a RANK on table1:

```
;with cte as
 (
   select *,
      -- assign a ranking for each customer
      RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY SAVED_DATE DESC) AS rnk
   from table1 
 )
select ...
from cte
join table2 as t2
  on cte.Template_ID = t2.Template_ID
WHERE cte.rnk <= 10 -- no filter for the n latest rows per curomer
```